# Magento2 - Set value for dropdown type product custom attribute programatically

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom, dropdown-attribute

I have a custom attribute with code '`manufacturer`'.

Its Catalog Input Type for Store Owner is '`Dropdown`'.

How can i set the value for this attribute programmatically on product save.
I am trying this, but unsuccessful

```
  $product->setManufacturer('ICM');
  $product->save();
```

What is the correct syntax for saving this type of attribute value

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the id of the option as parameter for `setManufacturer`.
If you don't know the ids you can retrieve first all the options for the `manufacturer` attribute and create an array where the key is the label and the value is the id.
Something like this (all needs to happen in a class)

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface
 */
private $attributeRepository;
/**
 * @var array
 */
private $options;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
    ....
) {
    ... 
    $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    ....
}

private function getOptions()
{
    if ($this->options === null) {
        try {
            $attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get('manufacturer');
            $this->options = [];
            foreach ($attribute->getOptions() as $option) {
                $this->options[$option->getLabel()] = $option->getValue();
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
             $this->options = [];
         }
    }
    return $this->options;
}
```

after this, in the same class, in the method that saves the products you can do this:

```
$optionLabel = 'ICM';
$product->setManufacturer($this->getOptions()[$optionLabel] ?? null);
$product->save();
```

(untested code so watch out for typos).